# SPARQL query cannot find page that should exist

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am writing a query in DBpedia live http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/ to return details of well known people. As a test case, I know there exists a page for the Roman Emperor Nero at http://dbpedia.org/page/Nero but my query does not return a row for him. My SPARQL query is:

```
# Runs in live (http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/)
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x0 ?name2 ?dob 
WHERE {
  ?x0 rdf:type foaf:Person.
  ?x0 rdfs:label ?name.
  ?x0 dbo:birthDate ?dob.
  FILTER REGEX(?name,"^Ner.*","i").
  BIND (str(?name) AS ?name2)
} ORDER BY ?name2 LIMIT 100
```

I checked the page http://dbpedia.org/page/Nero and it has the rdf:type, rdfs.label and dbo.birthDate properties referenced in my query. When I run the above query it returns 100 other people with name beginning "Ner" using the case insensitive version of REGEX.

So my question is: Why does the above query not return Nero in the list of results?

Answer (score 2):

First thing, note that on DBpedia, Nero (currently) comes in [result rows 109 and 110](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fx0%20%3Fname2%20%3Fdob%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3Fdob.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20REGEX%28%3Fname%2C%22%5ENer.*%22%2C%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28str%28%3Fname%29%20AS%20%3Fname2%29%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fname2%20LIMIT%20110%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), so you need at least 110 rows to see him.

Now, note that Nero's description [on DBpedia-Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Nero) is different than [on DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Nero) -- and that neither is correct.

Of particular note, see that on DBpedia-Live, Nero's `http://dbpedia.org/`**`property`**`/birthDate` has one value -- `1937-12-15 (xsd:date)` -- while on DBpedia, `http://dbpedia.org/`**`ontology`**`/birthDate` has two values -- `0037-12-15 (xsd:date)` and `1937-12-15 (xsd:date)`.

Also note that on DBpedia-Live, Nero has no `http://dbpedia.org/`**`ontology`**`/birthDate` value -- while on DBpedia, `http://dbpedia.org/`**`property`**`/birthDate` has no value.

These results should be of interest to you -- on [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx0%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3FdobONTOLOGY.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx0%20dbp%3AbirthDate%20%3FdobPROPERTY.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20REGEX%28%3Fname%2C%22%5ENero.*%22%2C%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28str%28%3Fname%29%20AS%20%3Fname2%29%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fname2%20LIMIT%20110%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), and on [DBpedia-Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20rdf%3Atype%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx0%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx0%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3FdobONTOLOGY.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx0%20dbp%3AbirthDate%20%3FdobPROPERTY.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20REGEX%28%3Fname%2C%22%5ENero.*%22%2C%22i%22%29.%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28str%28%3Fname%29%20AS%20%3Fname2%29%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fname2%20LIMIT%20110%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).